# Remove comments when compiling with hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat

Is it possible to remove comments from .sol files when compiling with hardhat?

Comment: Provide more information about your final goal, it could help to give you better answers. Do you need this to have a completely deterministic bytecode? To have verified contracts on Etherscan without comments while keeping them in your local `sol` files?

Comment: you could try something like hardhat preprocessor. it can be used to remove console.log entries, but you could adapt it to remove comments

Comment: @AndreaCiceri my goal is to remove all the comments when compiling the contract so on etherscan there wont be comments in the contract. The code should stay same, just without comments. i will give preprocessor a try. thanks much!